# Retrieving HttpClient service does not work with Blazor Client

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I can not retrieve the  default `HttpClient` injected by the server in the `Blazor` client.

**Configure**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                try
                {

                    ServiceProvider prov = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                    var returned = prov.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>();
                    if (returned == null) //returns null on Blazor Client 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("is null");
                    }
                    else Console.WriteLine(not null httpclient);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);

                }
            }
```

**P.S** 
Why does this code not work on the `Blazor` client and will work without problem on any typical `Asp Net Core` application ?

**P.S 2** After solving the problem for my given service by first adding it to the service collection and then using `GetService< >` i see that this however does not work for `HttpClient`.
So the server already injects in the `Client.Startup` a `HttpClient`; why can't i retrieve it ?

Comment: You're building another `ServiceProvider` before you register the `MyService` service using `ServicesCollection`,  and then you ask for `MyService` from the previously built `ServiceProvider`.

Comment: I thought the serviceprovider tracks the state of the servicecollection .So it works like a snapshot, i can retrieve only services added before i build the provider.

Comment: If you need `ServiceProvider` to resolve service to build another service, you could  simply use `AddSingleton<MyService>(sp=>{  /* now you get the service provider;*/  })`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
              services.AddSingleton<MService>(); 


}
```

Note: You should not create a ServiceProvider. It has already been created by code. All 
 you've got to do is add your object to the container.
 Incidentally, if you do create a ServiceProvider, the ConfigureServices method in which 
 it was created should return it, so other pieces of code can use it.

It is not clear why you want to access the HttpClient service in the ConfigureServices
method ! However you can do the following:
1.Inject the IServiceProvider and use it like this:

```
@inject IServiceProvider services

@functions {
    WeatherForecast[] forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {
        var client = services.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>();
        forecasts = await client.GetJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("/sample-data/weather.json");
    }
}
```

2. Build a service provider from the services accessible in the ConfigureServices
   method:

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

   ```
   IServiceProvider Services = services.BuildServiceProvider();
   var client = Services.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>();
   ```

   }

Hope this helps...

Comment: You are indeed right that first i must add the service then get the service proivder.However when i am trying to `provider.GetService<HttpClient>()` its says null, even though by default a `HttpClient` is already injected.

Comment: The problem is that i want to extract the `HttpClient` from the `IServiceCollection` provided by the `Blazor server`.With this client i want to `AddTransient` services that use this single instance of `HttpClient`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are looking for... However, if you wish to define services that employ HttpClient then inject the HttpClient into these services. In normal Blazor application there is a single HttpClient defined for you, and you can use it anywhere.But you cannot define these services as transient because HttpClient service is added as a Singleton. In more advanced scenarios you can use  HttpClientFactory on Razor Components, and perhaps Blazor soon enough.

Comment: I have solved the problem thanks to your answer.Thank you !